# ASP.NET Razor Pages Error: InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

So I'm relatively new to ASP.NET Razor and I'm getting a consistent error that I'm not sure how to fix. I've created an ASP.NET Core Web Application MVC with Razor Pages.

I'm currently getting the error: `InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()`
when I load the project. It's telling me that the error is in the line `email = Request.Form["email];`

File the error is relating to:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Login";

var email = "";
var pswd = "";
bool rem = false;

email = Request.Form["email"];
pswd = Request.Form["pswd"];
}
<div class="progress mt-5">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" 
style="width:40%"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="container mx-auto bg-warning" style="width:50%;">
    <h1 class="title" style="text-align:center">TestWebApp</h1>

    <form method="post" class="px-3 py-5">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text bg-primary border-0 text-light" style="width:100px">Email</span>
            </div>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" value="">
       </div>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text bg-primary border-0 text-light" style="width:100px">Password</span>
        </div>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd" value="@pswd">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="@rem"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

The weird thing is I ran this code multiple times before, just making small design changes with no relation to the form itself and it worked fine without an error but has now started showing this error and I'm not sure how to fix it. Would be very thankful for some help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what does `Request` stand for in your code. Because nothing in your page is named that way. If you have some sort of shortcut somewhere I guess you're getting the `Request` property from your model. So you're referring to the `PageModel`'s `Request` property that gets exposed because your model `IndexModel` inherits from `PageModel`.

If the aforementioned is true, then I suspect you're using the `Request.Form` in the wrong place here.

What are you trying to accomplish reading `Request.From` at that point in time, i.e - when the razor engine parses and renders your template? Please note, there's no form there yet. So that's probably why you're getting such error.

The error could be misleading because your code is messing with the request too early in the process. You're basically forcing the engine to read the form when nothing is there and the exception that pops out is telling you that the form doesn't have, neither  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` nor `multipart/form-data` as its `Content-Type` header value. But again, the main reason for the failure is that **you're using the `Request.Form` in the wrong place**.

Perhaps you should explain better what your final goal is, so we can get a better idea of what can be wrong?

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll try changing where I'm putting the `Request.Form` bit and see if that works, thanks. Basically I'm trying to get the input from the form and save it in a variable, if that helps at all.

Comment: Also, if it is in the wrong place, where is the place I should be putting it?

Comment: @TobyKing interesting question. That depends on where you are processing the value. If you want to get the email on the client side, use javascript/jquery as you'd normally do on web development. If on the other hand, you want the email in the server side, maybe to save it to a database or something like that, you should get your model to expose that as a property and receive the value on post via model binding features. The best I can do is point you to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio. Start there.